# What is the difference between Star Ocean: The Last Hope and the International Version?

Tags: version-differences, star-ocean-4

Apart from the obvious that one is in PAL compatible Regions (which make no difference anyway), what are the differences between getting Star Ocean: The Last Hope and the International Version of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest difference in the International Version of *Star Ocean: The Last Hope* is that it consist of one blu-ray disc, so there's no disk swapping discs like with the 360 version.

This edition also adds the Japanese voice tracks, portraits choices (3D and anime), and tweaked graphics. Manual targeting was added via the Start button.

I believe some additional [treasure chests](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/star-ocean-last-hope-international/38595-ps3-xbox-treasure-chest-differences.html) were added, along with the final ones being changed around a bit too changed a bit.

The Synthing priorities was also tweaked around a bit, making it harder to do certain exploits and harder to create strong weapons at lower levels. E.g., the Curry Rice priority was changed, so it's not the first priority anymore, so the 800%+ EXP exploit can't be used anymore. The "Laser Suit" for Bacchus on 360 it required a "Laser Oscillator" and "Gnomestone" while the International Version requires a "Laser Oscillator," "Thorstone," and the "'Aurora Ring' Symbol card."